# How to find all objects used inside oracle triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers

How to find all objects (like sequence, tables, views, functions, sp, pkg) used inside oracle triggers ?

Please help me.

thanks.

Comment: Maybe this would come to help [Schema object dependencies](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/dependencies.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use,

```
select * from user_dependencies where type = 'TRIGGER';
```

Instead of user_ you could also use all_ or dba_ to see extended details.